# Kendo Combobox - set multiple combobox values all coming from the database

Tags: javascript, kendo-datasource, kendo-combobox

I am having a lot of trouble with setting the values of my combo-boxes. The problem is that I have multiple combo-boxes, each dependent on the previous selected value from a combo-box. All the values are stored in a database. When I run an ajax request to get the values and set the combo-box values, every time I refresh my page the text on the combo-boxes are INCORRECT. And every time I load the page different text is displayed on the combo-box even though nothing has been changed. Has this got something to-do with the way I set the values? Or should there be a particular order considering each is dependent on the previous value? Can someone please help???

E.g.
    Sports (selected from 1st combo-box),
    Football (selected from 2nd combo-box),
    David Beckham (selected from 3rd combo-box)

Once all of this data is selected and saved to the database. On document ready I call an ajax request to get this data and set the combo-box values but, either the saved values is not displayed and shows a different value from the data-source or shows nothing at all. Every time the page is loaded it shows something else even the the right values is coming from the database.

Answer (score 2):

To have three dependent combo-boxes, it is better to use "cascadeFrom" property of kendo combo-box.
A simple example:

```
 <div>
     <input id="category" />
     <input id="sports" />
     <input id="player" />
 </div>

 <script>
  $("#category").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "categoryName",
    dataValueField: "categoryId",
    dataSource: [
        { categoryName: "Sports", categoryId: 1 },
        { categoryName: "Music", categoryId: 2 }
    ]
   });

  $("#sports").kendoComboBox({
    cascadeFrom: "category",
    dataTextField: "sportsName",
    dataValueField: "sportsId",
    dataSource: [
        { sportsName: "Football", sportsId: 1, categoryId: 1 },
        { sportsName: "Cricket", sportsId: 2, categoryId: 1 },
        { sportsName: "Pop", sportsId: 3, categoryId: 2 },
        { sportsName: "Rock", sportsId: 4, categoryId: 2 }
    ]
  });

  $("#player").kendoComboBox({
    cascadeFrom: "sports",
    dataTextField: "playerName",
    dataValueField: "playerId",
    dataSource: [
        { playerName: "David Beckham", playerId: 1, sportsId: 1 },
        { playerName: "Leonel Messi", playerId: 2, sportsId: 1 },
        { playerName: "Xavi", playerId: 3, sportsId: 1 },
        { playerName: "Raina", playerId: 4, sportsId: 2 },
        { playerName: "Gambhir", playerId: 4, sportsId: 2 },
        { playerName: "YXZ", playerId: 4, sportsId: 3 },
        { playerName: "ABC", playerId: 4, sportsId: 3 }
    ]
  });

   // To set value in combo-box
   $("#category").data('kendoComboBox').value(1);
   $("#sports").data('kendoComboBox').value(1);
   $("#player").data('kendoComboBox').value(2);

</script>
```

Here, I have hard coded the value to set in combo-box. You can pull data from database and set here.
Its good to save the value field of combo-box and use that to display the data.

Hope this helps.

[Reference Link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox)